# Is this underlining and quoting a standard way of marking names and nicknames in text?

Tags: hanja, orthography

In an [online version of the Bible](https://www.bible.com/bible/142/JHN.1.rnksv), 요한 is underlined in

> 그 이름은 요한이었다.  (His name is John.)

Is that a common thing?  Is it because it is a name, or because it is a foreign word?  One of the answers suggests this is a way of emphasis, but emphasis would not be particularly appropriate here.

The same version also starts with

> 태초에 ‘말씀’이 계셨다.

말씀 here is a metaphorical name for Jesus (“In the beginning was the Word”).  Is quoting such also common?  What are the "rules" for separating a term from its particle in that way?

[How to spot English loanwords and Hanja words in a text?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/how-to-spot-english-loanwords-and-hanja-words-in-a-text) asks about foreign words and Hanja, but the answers (so far) address only Hanja.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a Korean specific practice - this seems to be a carry over from English (or whatever original language that started this) versions of the Bible. See [this](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/09/22/01/2C9EDEED00000578-0-image-a-2_1442881810395.jpg) for an extensive amount of underlining of nouns.

Comment: No, we do not do that in English.  We don’t have particles in English, nor do we embed names into verbs.

Comment: "nor do we embed names into verbs" ... like boycott or lynch? Or how about: "It seems that Laing has out-Freuded Freud here." (found using Google Books) If anything, it's *Korean* that does not embed names into verbs.

Comment: There are noi names embedded into boycott or lynch.  "out-Freuded" is rare and notice there is a hyphen there.  A Korean might ask a parallel question to mine: "Does English typically use a hyphen when joining a noun to a verb?"  You say Korean doesn't embed names into verbs.  Do you mean the lack of space in what I quoted is an error or an uncommon thing?  If so, then you have answered the question in a comment.

Comment: P.S. Technically, "out-Freuded" is not embedding a name into a verb; it is using the name AS a verb.  Perhaps I misinterpreted the Korean: is 이었다 a verb or just a verb inflection?

Comment: Frankly, I have difficulty in understanding first question : Do you ask about underlining ? Or is there some Korean who do not call John 요한 ?

Comment: "Is this underlining and quoting a standard way of …"  If that is incomprehensible, perhaps a better writer than me can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't generally underline or quote to mark a person's name. However when we want to emphasize it, it can be underlined, quoted, or marked by dots above the characters, like [image].

Refer to the **[Korean Grammar Rules](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000209&mn_id=30)**(한글 맞춤법) by the [National Institute of Korean Language](https://korean.go.kr/):

#### Supplement 18. Emphasis marks (드러냄표; ˙ ) and underline ( ___ )

Used to indicate the notable or important parts of your sentence.

> 한글의 본디 이름은 [image]이다.

> 중요한 것은 [image]

가 아니라 [![][3]][3]

<sub>(source: [korean.go.kr](https://www.korean.go.kr/images/s_dic/rule01_new_07_02.gif))</sub>
이다.

> 지금 필요한 것은 _지식_이 아니라 _실천_입니다. 
> (I cannot underline in Stack Exchange, so think of text between _ to be underlined.)

Instead of emphasis marks and underlines, single quotation marks can be used.

> 한글의 본디 이름은 '훈민정음'이다.

> 중요한 것은 '왜 사느냐'가 아니라 '어떻게 사느냐'이다.

> 지금 필요한 것은 '지식'이 아니라 '실천'입니다.

---

I think almost no one uses emphasis marks to emphasize nowadays; most people use underlines, **bold characters**(**굵은체** or **볼드체**), 'quotes', or sometimes *oblique characters*(*이탤릭체*). I, however, am against the use of oblique characters in written Korean since it is hard to read.

---

There is no special way to distinguish Hanja words(한자어), pure Korean words(고유어, 순우리말), and foreign words(외래어). Even Koreans are confused of this.

For example, some Koreans confuse 생각, 마진(margin), 가십(gossip), 댐(dam) to be Hanja words. They may appear to be when written in Hangul, but they are not!

There are more words that are thought to be traditional Korean words, but are actually foreign words, such as 가방 (from Japanese Kaban `かばん`), 담배(tobacco) and so on!

(Actually we can tell if a word is Hanja, foreign or pure in most situations, since the words from each groups share common pronunciations. We have a sort of intuition that words like sushi and tempura are Japanese words and kimchi and bulgogi are Korean words, right?)

Comment: Interesting.  So apparently the translators were unaware of this, because emphasis is not the same as just clarifying that it is a title or name.

Comment: I guess that is just a special case of the website, where they underline every proper noun displayed. Have a look at [another site](http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_SAENEW/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=SAENEW&VL=43&CN=1&CV=99), where same content is written, and you can see that no underlines are present.

Comment: But the quote marks for 말슴 _are_ on that site.

Comment: Just an emphasis on the ‘saying’, I think. As you can see, only the first appearance of 말씀 is quoted. Note that there are no absolute rules on language, and in Korean texts what I have wrote in the answer is just ‘common’.

Comment: No, all three occurrences are in quotes on both sites.

Comment: And while it’s true that 유한 is not underlined there, it is rendered blue.  But so are many other words that have no special treatment in the first sit.

Comment: Why are you concentrating on such special websites? We cannot conclude that something is common or not only looking at only a few articles. For example, in [Korean bibles](http://mall.godpeople.com/img/previewImage3/9788992871709_8590441.jpg) in paper, no noun is generally underlined or quoted. As stated in the answer, **Koreans do use quotes or underlines, but to show emphasis or some special meaning.** Too many quotations make Korean text not readable. Also, 요한 is rendered blue in the other site, just because to indicate that when you click it, a brief explanation comes out, a link!

Comment: You can also refer to [some news in Korean](http://news.naver.com/main/hotissue/read.nhn?mid=hot&sid1=100&cid=1079165&iid=3213803&oid=022&aid=0003269353&ptype=052) or [wiki article](https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%A7%9E%EC%B6%A4%EB%B2%95) and see how Korean text is written, for your help.